# conda is suddenly unavailable

Tags: python, pip, conda

Conda was just fine. I tried to install ipdb with `conda install ipdb`. Then the problem appeared. The problem is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/bin/conda", line 7, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ImportError: No module named conda.cli
```

This problem is very strange. The reason I first used conda was because of this problem with pip.
when use pip, the error occurred as:

```
:~$ pip install ipdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cuiyujie/.local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ImportError: No module named cli.main
```

I tried to follow the answer on stackoverflow([Conda ImportError: No module named conda.cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784644/conda-importerror-no-module-named-conda-cli/44841860#44841860)). Added path: ``` export PYTHONPATH=``/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/lib/python3.7:/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages: $PYTHONPATH ```.
This error is missing. But another error seems to appear:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/bin/conda", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 112, in main
    from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
  File "/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .common.io import timeout
  File "/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 5, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, _base, as_completed
ImportError: No module named concurrent.futures
```

I tried to comment out the above changes and revert to the original. Later I found that Anaconda is not in the PATH with the following command.

```
 python
    ...
    >>> import sys
    >>> sys.path


['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/cuiyujie/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

But I can see in .bashrc:

```
 # added by Anaconda3 5.3.1 installer
167 # >>> conda init >>>
168 # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
169 __conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
170 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
171     \eval "$__conda_setup"
172 else
173     if [ -f "/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
174         . "/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
175         CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
176     else
177         \export PATH="/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
178     fi
179 fi
180 unset __conda_setup
181 # <<< conda init <<<
```

I tried to add my environment manually.

```
 export PYTHONPATH="/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.5:/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

The problem becomes:

```
  File "/home/cuiyujie/installPacket/Anaconda/install/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: try `python -m pip install -U pip`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does using conda to install a package change my python version and remove conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546450/how-does-using-conda-to-install-a-package-change-my-python-version-and-remove-co) Usually this is due to users trying to force a different Python version in their **base**, but can sometimes be triggered by other packages. I find it unbelievable that `conda install ipdb` would induce this. It is a `noarch` build and hence has zero constraints on the Python install.